# scriptaculous library grails

Tags: grails, libraries

I have a standard GSP that i'm trying to include scriptaculous ajax search with.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<title>Search</title>
<g:javascript library="scriptaculous" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Entry Search</h2>
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="autocomplete_parameter" />
    <span id="indicator1" style="display: none"> <img
        src="/images/spinner.gif" alt="Working..." />
    </span>
    <div id="autocomplete_choices" class="autocomplete"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    new Ajax.Autocompleter("autocomplete", "autocomplete_choices", "mySearch", {paramName: "value" indicator: 'indicator1'});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have entries in a database I'm trying to compare with (I know the lookup works because I can do the ajax search in the address bar and it returns)

So after doing an inspect element on the page it came to my attention that scriptaculous is still not being included in the page that gets generated. The scriptaculous JScript Script File is under web-app\js\prototype directory.  Am i missing anything that is causing scriptaculous not to be included and my Ajax.Autocompleter to throw an exception and not be included on the page?

Comment: What version of Grails?  If Grails 2.X did you install the Prototype plugin or just copy the js files from another source?

Comment: We went to the prototype webpage and downloaded the files and unzipped them into our project

Comment: @Kelly see previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery is the standard javascript library for Grails 2 the "approved" way to include prototype is to delete jQuery and install the [prototype plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/prototype).

I was able to get it to work without doing that by having all the files (prototype.js, scriptaculous.js, effects.js, etc) in `js/prototype` and adding a module to the `conf/ApplicationResources.groovy` file:

```
modules = {
  application {
    resource url:'js/application.js'
  }
  myCustomModuleName {
    resource url: [dir: "js/prototype", file: "prototype.js"], disposition: "head"
    resource url: [dir: "js/prototype", file: "scriptaculous.js"], disposition: "head"
  }
}
```

and then include this in your gsp

`<r:require modules="myCustomModuleName" />`

Once I did that and restarted the app I was able to use the scriptaculous Shake effect:

```
<div id="shakeMe">
  <a href="#" onclick="new Effect.Shake('shakeMe'); return false;">Shake!</a>
</div>
```

This uses the Grails Resource framework to include the javascript files.

Hopefully this does it for you!

Comment: so you put all the files in web-app\js\prototype right?  and then what do you do about the scriptaculous having a dependency on prototype?

Comment: The `<require modules... />` loads both javascript files in the `modules` definition (prototype.js and scriptaculous.js).  I think I made it confusing by naming the module the same as the the 'library'.. see my edit above.

Comment: ok, i'll have to try this out tomorrow at work... thanks kelly